# what are different state of object?

Tags: java

Recently I had an interview where I was asked "What are different states of object?"
I could not understand this question and I asked an interviewer to repeat.
Again question was like "what are different/various stages (previous it was states in question) of object?" still I didn't understand and again interviewer explained like "Do you know different states of objects like ***create*** and all"?

I answered like when we create object it goes to heap memory and after usage finished then it is eligible for garbage collection. 
Still interviewer was not satisfied with this answer. Again I was asked "What are different stages of object?"

Please explain me the interpretation of this question.

One more thing while you answer this question, try to start from ***create*** and go on because interviewer has given at least one stage/state of the object. If no then what would be the exact answer?

Comment: Sounds like a poor interviewer to me. Unfortunately as we can't read their mind, we can't really provide a good answer to this.

Comment: Creation, use, and clean up? even though clean up is by the garbage collector in java. We don't know what the interviewer meant.

Comment: In my experience, the best way to tackle vague questions like this is by first figuring out what it is exactly that the interviewer is trying to ask. For this, it's generally more productive to ask them specific questions rather than saying "I don't understand."

Answer (score 2):

I think the stages he was referring to were these below:

```
 1. Declaration: 
 2. Instantiation
 3. Initialization
```

Declaration is where you declare an Object and assign a reference variable to it.

```
Object obj;
```

Instantiation is where you use `new` operator that creates an Object.

```
 Object obj = new object();
```

Initialization happens when Object's constructor call is invoked.

```
Object obj = new object();
```

Comment: and garbage collection in the end

Comment: @Bingo If you consider garbage collector as the end stage then class loading would be the first stage. :)

Comment: I meant in reference of object state that - object will get garbage collected (in cases)